# drupal 7 webform add classes to submit button

Tags: theming, webforms

I am trying to add classes to my webform. In

**hook_webform_element**

I can do this

```
if ($element['#type'] == 'checkboxes') {
  $wrapper_classes = array(
    'form-item',
    'webform-component',
    'large-16 medium-8 small-24 columns',
    'webform-component-' . $type,
  );
}
else {
     $wrapper_classes = array(
    'form-item',
    'webform-component',
    'large-8 medium-8 small-24 columns',
    'webform-component-' . $type,
  );
}
```

But I do not seem to have access to the submit button. I need to add a couple of classes and also only do it on a certain form so suppose I need the $form_id.

Comment: did you try `hook_form_alter` from the Drupal Form API? Let me put this another way. Yes, a webform is made up of webform elements (because years ago they made their own form creation and storage mechanisms separate from Drupal) ... but it's still just a Form and they leverage the Drupal form api still for validation and processing etc. So a custom select widget would be a webform component, the submit button is just a plain HTML input submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this hook_form_alter(). As all the form element are available in hook_form_alter.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_YOUR_NODE_ID') {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'newclass';
    }
}
```